# Title for selected segment in UISegmentedControl disappears when taking a screenshot of my scrollview

Tags: ios, scrollview, screenshot, title

This is my code to take a screenshot of my scrollview :

```
UIImage* image = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_scrollView.contentSize, _scrollView.opaque, 0.0);
        {
            CGPoint savedContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
            CGRect savedFrame = _scrollView.frame;
            _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
            _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.contentSize.width, _scrollView.contentSize.height);

            [_scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
         }
```

I tried this with no success:

```
[_scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:_scrollView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Comment: Any help to this problem?